# Login issue with MSAL and AD B2C in Swift

Tags: swift, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to implement login in iOS app with MSAL and Azure AD B2C.

I tried setting multiple applications on Azure and added multiple policies, but none worked.

I am setting application like this:

```
self.application = try MSALPublicClientApplication(clientId: kClientID,
                                                               authority: try getAuthority(forPolicy: kSignupOrSigninPolicy),
                                                               redirectUri: "msal{my-code-from-azure}://auth")
```

This is code for auth:

```
func authorize() {
        do {

            let authority = try self.getAuthority(forPolicy: self.kSignupOrSigninPolicy)

            let parameters = MSALInteractiveTokenParameters(scopes: kScopes)
            parameters.authority = authority
            application.acquireToken(with: parameters) { (result, error) in
                if let result = result {
                    self.accessToken = result.accessToken
                    print("Access token is \(self.accessToken ?? "Empty")")
                } else {
                    print("Could not acquire token: \(error ?? "No error informarion" as? Error)")
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Unable to create authority \(error)")
        }
    }
```

This is log when application is created:

```
%@ TID=4374853 MSAL 0.5.0 iOS Sim 12.2 [2019-08-07 11:22:40] Default app's access group: "Masked(not-null)".
%@ TID=4374853 MSAL 0.5.0 iOS Sim 12.2 [2019-08-07 11:22:40] Using "Masked(not-null)" Team ID.
%@ TID=4374853 MSAL 0.5.0 iOS Sim 12.2 [2019-08-07 11:22:40] Init MSIDKeychainTokenCache with keychainGroup: Masked(not-null)
```

And this is log when login is performed:

```
%@ TID=4374853 MSAL 0.5.0 iOS Sim 12.2 [2019-08-07 11:32:27 - E1C7D48B-1947-41F1-AAC4-33A6C533019E] [MSAL] -[MSALPublicClientApplication acquireTokenWithParameters:(
    "https://{my-url}/user_impersonation"
)
                                     extraScopesToConsent:(null)
                                                  account:Masked(null)
                                                loginHint:Masked(null)
                                               promptType:MSALPromptTypePromptIfNecessary
                                     extraQueryParameters:(null)
                                                authority:<MSALB2CAuthority: 0x600000371860>
                                              webviewType:MSALWebviewTypeDefault
                                            customWebview:No
                                            correlationId:(null)
                                             capabilities:(null)
                                            claimsRequest:(null)]
%@ TID=4374853 MSAL 0.5.0 iOS Sim 12.2 [2019-08-07 11:32:27 - E1C7D48B-1947-41F1-AAC4-33A6C533019E] [MSAL] Beginning interactive flow.
%@ TID=4374853 MSAL 0.5.0 iOS Sim 12.2 [2019-08-07 11:32:27 - E1C7D48B-1947-41F1-AAC4-33A6C533019E] [MSAL] Resolving authority: Masked(not-null), upn: Masked(null)
%@ TID=4374853 MSAL 0.5.0 iOS Sim 12.2 [2019-08-07 11:32:27 - E1C7D48B-1947-41F1-AAC4-33A6C533019E] [MSAL] Resolved authority, validated: YES, error: 0
2019-08-07 13:32:33.320511+0200 PodMe[59184:4374853] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7F6AB8AB-D024-4FA1-BC2D-9D5CC042BA79/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2019-08-07 13:32:33.322370+0200 PodMe[59184:4374853] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
%@ TID=4374853 MSAL 0.5.0 iOS Sim 12.2 [2019-08-07 11:32:50 - E1C7D48B-1947-41F1-AAC4-33A6C533019E] [MSAL] No cached preferred_network for authority
%@ TID=4379306 MSAL 0.5.0 iOS Sim 12.2 [2019-08-07 11:32:50] Failed to initialize issuer authority with error MSIDErrorDomain, -51112
%@ TID=4379306 MSAL 0.5.0 iOS Sim 12.2 [2019-08-07 11:32:50 - E1C7D48B-1947-41F1-AAC4-33A6C533019E] Unsuccessful token response, error MaskedError(MSIDErrorDomain, -51100)
%@ TID=4379306 MSAL 0.5.0 iOS Sim 12.2 [2019-08-07 11:32:50 - E1C7D48B-1947-41F1-AAC4-33A6C533019E] [MSAL] Interactive flow finished result (null), error: -51100 error domain: MSIDErrorDomain
%@ TID=4379306 MSAL 0.5.0 iOS Sim 12.2 [2019-08-07 11:32:50 - E1C7D48B-1947-41F1-AAC4-33A6C533019E] [MSAL] acquireToken returning with error: (MSALErrorDomain, -50000) Masked(not-null)
Could not acquire token: Optional(Error Domain=MSALErrorDomain Code=-50000 "(null)" UserInfo={MSALErrorDescriptionKey=Authentication response received without expected accessToken, MSALInternalErrorCodeKey=-42008, MSALCorrelationIDKey=E1C7D48B-1947-41F1-AAC4-33A6C533019E})
```

Comment: Hi @Faruk. Does the `authority` argument look correct at runtime to you?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett I think so. I created application successfully with it.

Comment: Hi @Faruk. The error codes are listed [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-common-for-objc/blob/master/IdentityCore/src/MSIDError.h). It appears (i.e. `-51112`) you might be setting an invalid parameter.

Comment: @ChrisPadgett But it opens right web page. I just can't get access token

Comment: @Faruk if you're not getting an access token back, it's because the scope is wrong. Also this [sample has been updated](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-ios-swift-native-msal) if you want to use it.

Comment: @Faruk did you able to resolve this issue??

Comment: Me too facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As of 7/17/2020, there are few things to note to get the sample to work:

1. documentation from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-b2c-ios-swift-native-msal/microsoft-authentication-library-b2c-ios/ and https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-ios-swift-native-msal have a mistake.

They said:

```
<key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>msalyour-client-id-here</string>
            </array>
```

The sample is: msal

That is incorrect. The correct format is in https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc

In particular: msauth.[BUNDLE_ID] format

Also, make sure on portal, the redirect is "msauth.[BUNDLE_ID]://auth" format

This should fix the issue.

Personally, I made a mistake not giving permission that gave me error 51100. That was just me though.

Comment: This seems like a giant issue, if they really gave the wrong instructions in the documentation there. How come no one else seems to have run into this? Also, why would it matter what the format of the URL scheme is, as long as it's unique (which msal<client-id> also is)?

Comment: I don't work for MS, but from my experience, they are probably short staffed here, and it seems to involve several teams. There's several versions of b2c too. Reading and posting questions on github get you access to their engineers on this and they are generally pretty responsible (like one time some guy responded 3AM in the morning). Regarding schemes, I think Microsoft has lots of these 'conventions'. Once you know them, it's easy. Coming from other platforms that explicit define things might be thrown off of this practice.